# Leaflet.Heat issue with adding points with intensity

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap

My issue is when adding points to the leaflet.heat layer I cant seem to increase the point intensity. When I increase the intensity of a point ex. [lat, long, intensity] for leaflet.heat, no matter what I set the intensity as, it appears to be only one point on my map (a faint blue dot.)

The following is how I set up my heatmap

```
    var heat = new L.heatLayer(latlngArray, {
        maxZoom: 9,
        max: 10000000,
        radius : 25,
        blur : 15,
            });
```

and points are as follows

var latlngArray = [[10,10, "300"], ...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem with leaflet.heat.  The only change I ever saw with the rendered heatmap was when I set max < 1: `heat.setOptions({max:.0001});`

In the end, I switched to using [heatmap.js](https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js) since its value support worked for me out of the box.

Comment: I also recommend **heatmap.js**. Even with the fix @Mourner mentioned I couldn't bring **leaflet.heat** to work properly for me.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in how it handled the max option. It should be fixed in the latest Leaflet.heat release. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your zoom levels! The leaflet heat package is designed to increase intensity as you zoom into the map. This is to make sure the map looks legible even when you zoom out and still be able to see individual data points when you zoom in